How to save plugins in rqt_bag, namely the image plugin?
Situation: I'm using rqt/rqt_bag to review saved bags. The bags that I'm dealing with have image messages, so I'm using the image plugin to display the image (right click -> view -> etc.).
However, when I close the program and reopen it, the image plugin is not saved (no longer shows up), and I have to click around to bring it up again. I tried using the perspective files to save the plugins that are currently in use, but it seems like only the "main" (?) plugins are saved. For example, the bag plugin stays up, the shell plugin stays up, etc. (accessible via the Plugins button on the toolbar), but not the image plugin for bags. I'm thinking that perhaps the reason why it doesn't save is because a bag must be loaded in order for the image plugin to be running?
It would be great if there were a solution similar to a .rviz file, but for rqt. I'm using ros2 if that matters.
